# XORing a positive integer with negative complemet two

Tags: python, xor, twos-complement

First, I have tried XOR-ing  1 and -1 in python.
since representations are:

```py
bin(1) == '0b1', 
bin(-1) == '-0b1'
```

I couldn't guess what the outcome would be. I've expected something like 'negative zero' - sign bit negative, all other bits zero.

Well, I've got -2.

Next, I've tried to `XOR` some positive number `n`, with the it's twos-complement negative corresponding integer.

Examples:

`3 ^ (-1)` results in: `-4`

`2 ^ (-6)` results in: `-8`

For every integers m,n such that:

`2**(k-1) <= n < 2**(k)` and `m = (-1) * ((2**k)-n)`

We get:

```
n ^ m == (-1)*(2**k)
```

What is the logic behind that?

Comment: Firstly `3^(-3) = -2`

Comment: 3 and -3 are not two's complement for each other...

Answer (score 0):

Python uses two's complement to represent negative binary numbers.

`binary(-x) = complement( binary(x) ) + 1`

For example:

```
3 = 0b...00011
-3 = complement(3) + 1 = 0b...11100 + 1  = 0b...11101
```

The ... shows that it extends to infinity.
[source](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators)

The rest follows.

Comment: Please edit my answer if you find it to be a correct solution.

Comment: I learned 2's complement by `inverting then add 1`, not your way.

Comment: They are equivalent. complement(x-1) = complement(x) + complement(-1) = complement(x) + 1.

Comment: Can you prove the firest `=` in your last comment? Besides, I believe the 2's complement of -3 is 0b11...1101, not your 0b... 11110.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I made a mistake there. It's fine now.

Answer (score 0):

The bit patterns for the values of m and n that have been chosen match until the kth bit.  All bits higher than k-1 are set.  This corresponds to the binary representation of -(2**k).  Below shows n and m for k = 3 as 8-bit patterns.

```
from numpy import binary_repr

def do_k( k ):
    for n in range(2**(k-1), 2**k):
        bn = binary_repr( n , 8 ) # n for 8 bits
        m = (n-2**k)
        bm = binary_repr( m , 8 ) # m for 8 bits
        print( bn )
        print( bm )
        print( binary_repr( n ^ m, 8 ) , n, m, n ^ m, '\n' )

do_k(3)
00000100   4
11111100  -4 = 4 - 8
11111000 4 -4 -8 

00000101   5
11111101  -3 = 5 - 8
11111000 5 -3 -8 

00000110   6 
11111110  -2 = 6 - 8
11111000 6 -2 -8 

00000111   7
11111111  -1 = 7 - 8 
11111000 7 -1 -8
```

The result pattern is 'caused' by the selection pattern. np.binary_repr is very useful for exploring bit patterns in integers. The second parameter is how many bits to show.

Answer (score -1):

You assume [ones complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement) is used despite talking of twos complement. Actually, I'm not aware that it is practically used anywhere due its disavantages (non-unique representation of zero, special handling needed to cross sign change boundary), at the very least [twos complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) is far more frequently used. Surely no programming language I know of lets you determine, which kind of complement to use.